# File in the same subdirectory as the HTML in CMS

Tags: apache-2.2, .htaccess, rewrite, alias

I have a CMS installation with a link such as

```
journal.org/archives/volume136/number10/37362-49383
```

I want to place a few PDF files in the same directory as the above HTML such that the PDFs are accessible from

```
journal.org/archives/volume136/number10/1.pdf
journal.org/archives/volume136/number10/2.pdf
```

However, after creating the physical directories in the server, I am not able to access

```
journal.org/archives/volume136/number10/37362-49383
```

It gives the error

> Forbidden You don't have permission to access /archives/ on this
>   server.

I neither want to change the name of the sef url so that it don't match the directory name, nor, change the name of the directory. Is there a better solution on apache level?

Answer (score 0):

We need to exclude the particular directory in htaccess file using conditional rewrite. In my case, it is

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/archives/
```